# how to select/target a submit button among several buttons from html to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, addeventlistener

I want to select a button from a markup that contains three buttons, I tried calling the specified one directly but the code is not responding, but when I try to add the even listener on the body,obviously it takes the effect on the three buttons, which I don't like because I want to use them for special purposes like add and clear.

```
 <div id = "evnt-sec">
  <div class ="form-container">
    <h1>type your desired language here</h1>
    <form  id = 'task-form'>
      <div>
        <input type="text" class="type" id="task">
        <input type="submit" class="btn " value="add">
      </div>
      
    </form>
  </div>
      
    <ul>
     
    </ul>
    <div id="spa">
      <h1>type your desired language here</h1>
      <form id="task-form2">
        <input type="text" class="type filter">
        <input type="submit" class="btn " id="yes" value="clear">
      </form>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

That is the html for refrence. My aim exactly is to target the first input of type submit with value of `add` to add some created items to the empty 'ul' tag.

```
//document.body.addEventListener('submit' , addTask)
const additem = document.querySelector('#task');
const form = document.querySelector('.form-container');
const filter = document.querySelector('#spa input');
const clear = document.querySelector('#spa');
const listfat = document.querySelector('#evnt-sec ul');
console.log(form);
console.log(additem);
loadEventListeners();

function loadEventListeners() {
  form.addEventListener('submit' , addTask);
  //filter.addEventListener('click' , keyUp);
 // clear.addEventListener('submit' , clearItem);
}
form.addEventListener('submit' , function(e){
  if (additem.value ===''){
  alert('no value has been passed');}
const item = document.createElement('li');
item.className = 'append';
item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(additem.value));
const link = document.createElement('a');
item.appendChild(link);
link.innerHTML = '<i class ="fa fa-remove"></i>';
console.log(item);
additem.value =' ';
listfat.appendChild(item);
e.preventDefault();
});
```

And that is my js code above for refrence. I tried to grab the parent by using 'form-container' but it doesn't work, by using task-form yet it doesn't work and lastly by using the body the three buttons in my markup respond which is not what I want, since the code work by adding event on the body makes me believe that probably there's nothing wrong with the "function part of code".

I think I need more explanation on how to target the button and if possible I also need an explanation why the code isn't responding properly as this will really help me.

Comment: `e.submitter.id`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent#examples

Answer (score 1):

> my aim exactly is to target the first input of type submit with value
> of add

```
document.querySelector("input[type='submit'][value='add']").addEventListener(...)
```

But really, the clicking of the `submit` button will automatically trigger the `submit` event of the `form`, so you probably should target that instead:

```
document.querySelector("#task-form").addEventListener("submit", ...);
```

But, in actuality, your use case doesn't seem like you are actually submitting form data anywhere, in which case, you should not be using a `form` element in the first place, nor any submit buttons. You need regular buttons and handle their `click` event.

You also seem to have a lot of unnecessary code and your `if` condition's true block contains code that should run when the test is `false`.

```js
const addItem = document.querySelector('input[type="button"][value="add"]');
const task = document.querySelector('#task');
const clear = document.querySelector('#spa');
const listfat = document.querySelector('#evnt-sec ul');

addItem.addEventListener('click' , function(e){
  if (task.value ===''){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('no value has been passed');
  } else {
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    item.className = 'append';
    item.textContent = task.value;
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    item.appendChild(link);
    link.innerHTML = '<i class ="fa fa-remove"></i>';
    console.log(item);
    task.value ='';
    listfat.appendChild(item);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id = "evnt-sec">
  <div class ="form-container">
    <h1>type your desired language here</h1>
      <div>
        <input type="text" class="type" id="task">
        <input type="button" class="btn " value="add">
      </div>   
  </div>
  <ul></ul>
  <div id="spa">
    <h1>type your desired language here</h1>
      <input type="text" class="type filter">
      <input type="button" class="btn " id="yes" value="clear">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work, is there any other thing i need to note because when i console.log it, it gives out  the button,which means i target it correctly ,,,,,,i don't just understand

Comment: @Clax What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error in your console?

Comment: i've also tried #task-form

Comment: i didn't get an error, it doesn't respond to the function code,so by clicking on the button the page always reload without performing the role in which i addea preventDefault to the code

Comment: @Clax See my updated answer, which shows the add button working correctly now.